# Setting seed of GKARC4RandomSource

Tags: swift, random, gamekit

I'm using GKARC4RandomSource (from GameKit) to generate random numbers. After setting my seed I generate some random numbers. On the same instance, but latter, I set the exact same seed and I'm generating again some numbers. Since the seed is the same I'm expecting the same numbers, but this does not happen. What is am I missing?
Code:

```
let randSource = GKARC4RandomSource()

    func foo() {
        print("1st sequence")
        randSource.seed = "seed".data(using: .utf8)!
        for _ in 0...10 {
            print(randSource.nextInt())
        }
    }


    func bar() {
        print("2nd sequence")
        randSource.seed = "seed".data(using: .utf8)!
        for _ in 0...10 {
            print(randSource.nextInt())
        }
    }

    foo()
    bar()
```

Output:
1st sequence
1077893367
-527596564
188760480
-1473410833
1247450388
155479986
-1227640578
-1952625186
-1819582711
1494875350
238061911
2nd sequence
-815382461
1319464721
-496336642
1307036859
-1543687700
1786062933
63740842
657867659
-1908618575
360960015
75414057

Comment: Please show a (minimal) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for GKARC4RandomSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkarc4randomsource) suggests using the `seed` in the initializer.

> Any two random sources initialized with the same seed data will
>   generate the same sequence of random numbers. To replicate the
>   behavior of an existing GKARC4Random​Source instance, read that
>   instance’s seed property and then create a new instance by passing the
>   resulting data to the init(seed:​) initializer.

If you use `init(seed:)`, it works:

```
func foo() {
    print("1st sequence")

    let seed = "seed".data(using: .utf8)!
    let randSource = GKARC4RandomSource(seed: seed)
    for _ in 0...10 {
        print(randSource.nextInt())
    }
}


func bar() {
    print("2nd sequence")

    let seed = "seed".data(using: .utf8)!
    let randSource = GKARC4RandomSource(seed: seed)
    for _ in 0...10 {
        print(randSource.nextInt())
    }
}

foo()
bar()
```

**Output**

> ```
> 1st sequence
> -907495547
> -1853348607
> -891423934
> -1115481462
> -1946427034
> -1478051111
> 1807292425
> 525674909
> -1209007346
> -1508915292
> -1396618639
> 2nd sequence
> -907495547
> -1853348607
> -891423934
> -1115481462
> -1946427034
> -1478051111
> 1807292425
> 525674909
> -1209007346
> -1508915292
> -1396618639
> ```

Comment: HackingWithSwift made a useful article about this too.   https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/35/6/shuffling-an-array-with-gameplaykit-arraybyshufflingobjectsin